# Custom IHttpControllerSelector and WebApi HelpPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I implemented the `IHttpControllerSelector` found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx) in order to split my routes between Anonymous and Authenticated controllers, same as V1 and V2 were done in the example.

When I did that, I noticed the HelpPage area that comes with the sample WebApi Application in VS2013 was broken, as below:

[image: HelpPage does not understand {namespace} RouteParam]

I tried linking the `IHttpControllerSelector` to the `HelpController`, doing this in the constructor:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
```

But it did not help.

Has anyone used that sample and fixed the HelpPage?

The help generators are all kind of automagical, so I believe poking at them would consume a lot of time.